# "Cannot GET / " when combine all modules on one page?

Tags: reactjs, express, proxy, get

guys,I have a problem when I render all React modules on one page.

All 3 modules works fine at separate port.  But when I combine them using method like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <title>FEC Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="http://localhost:3000/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:3001/b5/undle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:3009/bundle.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

var port = 4567;
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/:id', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server listening at http://localhost:${port}
```

And it will give me an err when I combine them to the new page

```
GET http://localhost:4567/ 404 (Not Found)

Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:4567/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Do you guys have any idea, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Serving point (in URL): `/<SOME_ID>`

```
app.use('/:id', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

Serving point (in URL): `/`

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

I hope this helps.